# Using .env variables in a 'use client' component in Next.js

Tags: next.js

I have a 'use client' Apollo context wrapper component that needs to access a GraphQL URL and the access token from my .env file. However, as this is being rendered client side I can't access my .env vars.

Is there a method to do this in Next.js `v13`?

My code:

```
'use client';

// ^ this file needs the "use client" pragma

import { ApolloLink, HttpLink } from '@apollo/client';
import {
  ApolloNextAppProvider,
  NextSSRInMemoryCache,
  NextSSRApolloClient,
  SSRMultipartLink,
} from '@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/ssr';

const { GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT, CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN } = process.env;

// have a function to create a client for you
export function makeClient() {
  const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
    headers: {
      authorization: CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN ? `Bearer ${CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN}` : '',
    },
    fetchOptions: { cache: 'no-store' },
  });

  return new NextSSRApolloClient({
    // use the `NextSSRInMemoryCache`, not the normal `InMemoryCache`
    cache: new NextSSRInMemoryCache(),
    link:
      typeof window === 'undefined'
        ? ApolloLink.from([
            // in a SSR environment, if you use multipart features like
            // @defer, you need to decide how to handle these.
            // This strips all interfaces with a `@defer` directive from your queries.
            new SSRMultipartLink({
              stripDefer: true,
            }),
            httpLink,
          ])
        : httpLink,
  });
}

// you need to create a component to wrap your app in
export function ApolloWrapper({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) {
  // @ts-ignore
  return <ApolloNextAppProvider makeClient={makeClient}>{children}</ApolloNextAppProvider>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I read a little more into the next docs and you need to use NEXT_PUBLIC_ prefix on env variables names so the build will not that it's safe to compile as apart of a client side component.

updated code

```
'use client';

// ^ this file needs the "use client" pragma

import { ApolloLink, HttpLink } from '@apollo/client';
import {
  ApolloNextAppProvider,
  NextSSRInMemoryCache,
  NextSSRApolloClient,
  SSRMultipartLink,
} from '@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/ssr';

// eslint-disable-next-line
const uri = process.env['NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT'];
// eslint-disable-next-line
const authorization = process.env['NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN'];

// have a function to create a client for you
export function makeClient() {
  const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri,
    headers: {
      authorization: authorization ? `Bearer ${authorization}` : '',
    },
    fetchOptions: { cache: 'no-store' },
  });

  return new NextSSRApolloClient({
    // use the `NextSSRInMemoryCache`, not the normal `InMemoryCache`
    cache: new NextSSRInMemoryCache(),
    link:
      typeof window === 'undefined'
        ? ApolloLink.from([
            // in a SSR environment, if you use multipart features like
            // @defer, you need to decide how to handle these.
            // This strips all interfaces with a `@defer` directive from your queries.
            new SSRMultipartLink({
              stripDefer: true,
            }),
            httpLink,
          ])
        : httpLink,
  });
}

// you need to create a component to wrap your app in
export function ApolloWrapper({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) {
  // @ts-ignore
  return <ApolloNextAppProvider makeClient={makeClient}>{children}</ApolloNextAppProvider>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For an environment variable to be accessible on the client (the browser), you need to prefix it with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`, as the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser) says:

> `Non-NEXT_PUBLIC_` environment variables are only available in the Node.js environment, meaning they aren't accessible to the browser (the client runs in a different environment).

> In order to make the value of an environment variable accessible in the browser, Next.js can "inline" a value, at build time, into the js bundle that is delivered to the client, replacing all references to `process.env.[variable]` with a hard-coded value. To tell it to do this, you just have to prefix the variable with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`. For example:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_SOME_VARIABLE_NAME=abcdefghijk
```